# how to select all of data what same id using where in

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
table A

id value
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

I have table like above.

and my sql query

'select * from A as a where a.id in (1,3,2,3,3,1) order by field (a.id, 1,3,2,3,3,1)'

result is

```
id value
1    a
3    c
2    b
```

but I want to select

```
id value
1    a
3    c
2    b
3    c
3    c
1    a
```

like this..

how to can I do it?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your table with a derived table that contains the list of `id`s to select and the sequence, like:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 seq, 1 id
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 1
) x ON x.id = a.id
ORDER BY x.seq
```

With this solution, you can order as you wish without actually displaying the ordering column in the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you want, without using dynamic SQL, would be a union query:

```
SELECT id, value, 1 AS pos FROM A WHERE id = 1 UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, 2 FROM A WHERE id = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, 3 FROM A WHERE id = 2 UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, 4 FROM A WHERE id = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, 5 FROM A WHERE id = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, 6 FROM A WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY pos;
```

Note: You don't need a subquery to generate the ordering you want.

I suspect that you are looking for a way to generate some number of records in a result set based on state contained within the table.  SQL is a declarative language, and is not really good at creating new data.  Your business application is usually what does this.  So, the verbosity of the above union query arises because SQL is not articulate at generating data.

Comment: thank you. your query works.
But I want more simple query.

Comment: Is sure? Could you tell me why your query perform better than my accepted query?

Comment: The accepted answer has an unnecessary subquery.  You don't need a subquery here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "OR" Operator here for your query. It will give you all the result with id has a value of 1 or 2 or 3.

So here is your select as below.

Select * from A where id=1 OR id=2 Or id=3 order by id